# How can I convert strings to operators in Java?

Tags: java

I have "+" and I want to use it as "if(1 + 2 == 3)"

Comment: Do you mean that you want to know how to write a program that parses a mathematical expression (like "1 + 2 == 3")?

Comment: Java does not have eval, if that's what you mean.  For that, use JavaScript / ECMAScript.

Comment: might want to try http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JANINO/Home

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to evaluate "1+2" as a mathematical equation: [Evaluating a math expression given in string form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/java-evaluate-string-to-math-expression)

If you want to evaluate if(1+2==3) as an if statement, java should do that for you.